# Running MapReduce on HBase gives Zookeeper error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am doing a test project with Hadoop and HBase. Currently the cluster has 2 Ubuntu VMs hosted on a Windows machine.

I am able to perform PUT, QUERY and DELETE operation remotly (in my host machine) using following HBase Java API configuration

```
config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.56.90");  
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2222");
```

When I am trying to run a HBase MapReduce job on Windows with the same config as above, I am getting following error

```
    13/03/24 06:11:03 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:Joel cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-Joel\mapred\staging\Joel290889388\.staging to 0700
java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-Joel\mapred\staging\Joel290889388\.staging to 0700
```

From what I have read on the web, there seems to be a problem with running MapReduce jobs on Windows. So I tried running the MapReduce job on Linux by using "java - jar MR.jar".

On Linux, I can't connect to Zookeeper. For unknown reason, Zookeeper host and port are getting reseted on the client side

```
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=3.5.0-23-generic
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=hduser
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/hduser
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/hduser/testes
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.56.90:2222 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 11552@node01
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server node01/192.168.56.90:2222. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to node01/192.168.56.90:2222, initiating session
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server node01/192.168.56.90:2222, sessionid = 0x13d9afaa1a30006, negotiated timeout = 180000
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closed zookeeper sessionid=0x13d9afaa1a30006
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x13d9afaa1a30006 closed
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
13/03/24 05:59:33 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/03/24 05:59:33 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 11552@node01
13/03/24 05:59:33 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
13/03/24 05:59:33 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
```

Judging from log above, it connects correctly to node01:2222 (node01 resolves to 192.168.56.90). But for some reason, it changes to localhost:2181 and it then gives a connection refused error.

How can I fix this issue to get a MR jobs running on Linux, on the same machine as Zookeeper is running?

Version: Hbase 0.94.5 / Hadoop 1.1.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set the hbase.master also.

also check the /etc/hosts file and see if it is correct. Are you able to telnet to the zookeeper using that connection info?

```
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.56.90");  
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2222");
config.set("hbase.master", "some.host.com:60000")
```